How can I assign roles for third-party users in Android Management API on Google Cloud Console?
I have developed a Mobile Device Management application using the Android Management API, which was working perfectly fine. However, it only works for the owner's email address. So, when I tried to add another third-party user and assign them the roles for Android Management User and Owner, I encountered an error.
The error message:

Error retrieving token: Error: Caller is not authorized to manage project

I followed the below steps to add a new service account and assign the Android Management User role:

Signed in to the Google API Console.
Opened the Credentials page and selected the project that has the Android Management API enabled.
Clicked on Create credentials > Service account key.
From the dropdown menu, I selected "New service account" and provided a name for the service account.
I selected my preferred key type and clicked on Create. The new public/private key pair was generated and downloaded to my machine, and I ensured to store it securely.
Opened the IAM page and added the service account I had just created as a member.
I selected the role "Android Management User" and clicked on Save.
Optionally, I added additional project owners by granting the Owner role to existing project members.

Could you please suggest a solution to the error I am encountering?

I believe you were following this documentation when you created the service account and has quoted:

To access the Android Management API your service account requires the androidmanagement.enterprises.manage permission, which can be granted by the Android Management User role (or roles/androidmanagement.user).

With the concern you encountered, same scenario was encountered by stamppot, by which they created a new project and created a new service account with the "Owner" role before enabling the Android Management API.

To call the API from a server, you need to enable the Android Management API for your project and create a
service account. To access the Android Management API your service account requires the
androidmanagement.enterprises.manage permission, which can be granted by the roles/androidmanagement.user role.
Kindly refer to this to know more about creating a service account (AMAPI).

Hi @PAkultie, thank you for your reply. Could you please provide a step-by-step guide?
